# Creating logical array from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very large numpy array in Python full of meteorological data. In order to observe flawed data, I would like to look at every value and test it to see if it is less than -1. Eventually I would like to represent this with a logical array of 0's and 1's with 1 representing indices where the value is less than -1 and zeros representing all others. I have tried using the numpy.where funtion as follows

```
logarr = np.where(metdat < -1)
```

which returns the original array and the array of zeros for when this condition is true (around 200 times). I have tried using the numpy.where syntax laid out in Sci.Py.org where

```
logarr = np.where(metdat < -1 [1,0])
```

but my program dislikes the syntax. What am I doing wrong or would anyone recommend a better way of going about this?

Thanks,
jmatt

Comment: You misplaced the brackets. Try: `np.where(metdat < -1)[1][0]`

Comment: or this version....   a = np.array([0,-2,1,1,0,-2,0])  using ...  np.where(a<-1,1,0)  yields ....
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])

Answer (score 1):

This works for your case, which directly converts the type from `logical` to `int`:

```
(matdat < -1).astype(int)
```

Or for `np.where`, the syntax needs to be:

```
np.where(matdat < -1, 1, 0)
```